# textread does not read data correctly from file

Tags: matlab

I am using the following code to read from a file in MATLAB .

```
A=textread('A.txt');
B=textread('B.txt');
F=textread('F.txt');
LB=textread('LB.txt');
options = optimset('LargeScale','off','Simplex','on');

disp('Main Solution')
[X,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = linprog(-F,A,B,[],[],LB,[],[],options);
-fval
exitflag 
output
```

The actual data in the file is as following like the image :

[image]

But MATLAB reads this as like follows :

[image]

Why ? Is there any problem ? First data is 1674.25 but MATLAB reads it as like 0.1665 . WHy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll look closely, you will see that F is displayed like

```
1.0e+004 *
...
...
```

which means that all the values in the columns are actually multiplied by a 10000 factor. Thus 0.1665 * 10000 = 1665 which is approx 1674.25.

**NB1:** Mathworks recommends `textscan()` instead of `textread()`;

**NB2:** For immediate feedback from the console about a problem, try the standard command `why` in command window.

Answer (score 1):

It is reading the file correctly. What you're seeing is only a display issue. Notice the `1.0e+004 *` at the top of the listing. Try typing 'format longg' and then look at the values, or else just type `F(1)` to look at the first value.